# CSS Positioning Error in WebKit Browsers

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, css-float, positioning

I've tried everything and I cannot get this overlay to work in Chrome or Safari... any ideas? The arrows should be over the thumbs like they are in Firefox and IE.

**In Chrome:** 
[image: Chrome and safari]

**In Firefox:** 
[image: Firefox]

**My Code:**

```
.hm_tst_dv_img {
    height: 80px;
    width: 131px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3px 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hm_tst_dv_img_thumb {
    height: 80px;
    width: 131px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 90;
}

.hm_tst_dv_img_overlay {
    height: 80px;
    width: 131px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```
<div class="hm_tst_dv_img">
    <div class="hm_tst_dv_img_thumb">
        <img alt="" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>
            uploads/testimonials/thumb_
            <?php echo $testimonial->image; ?>"
            width="131" height="80" />
    </div>
    <div class="hm_tst_dv_img_overlay">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="PlayTestmoinalVideo(<?=$i;?>)">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/testimonial_overlay.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.hm_tst_dv_img_overlay {
    height: 80px;
    width: 131px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

I wouldn't mix positioning and floats if you can avoid it.